# Omnisharp for Emacs doesn't work

Tags: c#, windows, curl, emacs

I tried recently to work with C# with Emacs24. I found https://github.com/sp3ctum/omnisharp-emacs I installed it with MELPA. Then I run it. Nothing happened. I wonder what went wrong. I think I don't have curl installed on my Windows machine. I downloaded some kind of curl but I don't know how to use it and link it to my Emacs. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things spring to mind.

1. Are you running the OmniSharp server? OmniSharp for Emacs relies on OmniSharp server for its completions. You can find it [here](https://github.com/nosami/OmniSharpServer). Compile it, and run it against a Visual Studio/Mono solution - e.g. OmniSharp.exe -s path/to/solution
2. You mentioned curl - it needs to be in your windows PATH somewhere. Stick curl.exe in a folder (for example, C:\tools) and add C:\tools to your path. There are a couple of ways to do that.

   - You can add it to your path at the OS level ([this](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) link will show you how) and restart Emacs.
   - You can add to your PATH within Emacs with a bit of lisp. This will set your PATH environment variable within Emacs only. Add it to your dotemacs and evaluate it or restart Emacs.

     > (setenv "PATH" (concat "C:/tools;" (getenv "PATH")))

I hope this helps and good luck - OmniSharp is awesome, and I use it daily.

Simon